# Python importing function to package level

Tags: python, import, module, package

I found a couple of different [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302754/python-submodule-imports-using-init-py) and related questions here already but still I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have a python app with layout like this:

```
main.py
sources/
    __init__.py
    utils.py
```

My `__init__.py` contains:

```
from sources.utils import show
```

where *show* is a function defined in *utils*

I want to be able to write in main.py:

```
from sources import show
show()
```

but instead I get an error `ImportError: cannot import name 'show'`

Any help will be greatly appreciated

---

EDIT:

Seems that the problem is caused by the PyCharm IDE I'm using. The same code being run in python directly from linux console works like charm.

Sorry for bothering you guys and thank you for help.

Best Regards,
Max

Comment: change `__init__.py` to be `from utils import show`

Comment: @reptilicus Don't you mean `from .utils` (with the `.` relative import syntax) ?

Comment: Thanks for quick respnse, but it didn't change much. Now the PyCharm IDE is complaining about unresolved reference to 'utils' and the error remains.

Comment: @MaxPasek Can you provide the full Traceback?

Comment: The traceback was supposed to be here but I already found the answer. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [official recommendations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FutureProofPython#Absolute_imports):

> Python 2.x, imports are implicitly relative. For instance, if you're editing the file `foo/__init__.py` and want to import the module at `foo/bar.py`, you could use `import bar`.
>
> In Python 3.0, this won't work, as all imports will be absolute by default. You should instead use `from foo import bar`; if you want to import a specific function or variable from bar, you can use relative imports, such as `from .bar import myfunction`)

Either use absolute import in `__init__.py` (`from sources.util import show`) -- or explicit relative import (`from .util import show`).

Given this setup:

```
sh$ cat sources/utils.py 
def show():
    print("show")

sh$ cat sources/__init__.py 
from sources.utils import show
# could be
# from .utils import show

sh$ cat main.py 
from sources import show

show()
```

It will work as expected both in Python 2 & 3:

```
sh$ python2 main.py 
show
sh$ python3 main.py 
show
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`__init__.py`

```
import utils
show = utils.show
```

`main.py`

```
from sources import show
show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen in comments....

Change `__init__.py` to be

```
from utils import show
```