# Cannot Solve "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am running the project and shows this  error. I have googled and tried some of the solutions but doesn't seem to work.

```
File "/home/bs-094/Dev/backend/busgroup-backend/src/bus_portal_backend/apps/inquiry/forms/inquiry_details.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..models.inquiry import Inquiry
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

My folder structure is

```
busgroup-backend
 src
  bus_portal_backend
   apps
    inquiry
      models
       _init_.py
       inquiry.py
      forms
       inquiry_details.py
```

It would be great help is anyone helps me solve the problem. I am fairly new to django. Thanks

**EDIT**:
**Here's what solved my problem**, I had to import in this way

```
from bus_portal_backend.apps.inquiry.models import Inquiry
```

Also, I was running with debugger. My script path was `busgroup-backend/src/manage.py`, I changed it to `/home/bs-094/Dev/backend/busgroup-backend/src/manage.py`, which made me run the project successfully.

Comment: tried this ?   -   `from models.inquiry import Inquiry`

Comment: yeah. it  says  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`

Answer (score 1):

`forms` does not appear to contain an `__init__.py` file, and so Python doesn't think it's a package. Therefore an attempt to import from `..models` is an attempt to ascend above the current package's root (because `...busgroup-backend/src/bus_portal_backend/apps/inquiry/forms/inquiry_details.py` is actually a standalone module).

Relative imports only work within a package. Therefore you should make both `forms` and `models` subpackages of `inquiry` by creating `inquiry__init__.py` as well.

Comment: So shall I make another `__init__.py` inside `forms`?  My models/__init__.py has `from .inquiry import *` inside it.

Comment: I think you'll need both, but you won't break anything by experimenting. Be bold!

Comment: Can you explain me where do I create `inquiry__init__.py` and what do I write inside it? Creating __init__.py inside forms doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: No. there's plenty of reference material. Start at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) and ask specific questions if there are things you don't understand.

Comment: This wasn't meant to be unkind, by the way, but to ensure you got the information you needed. You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24303380/146073) helpful!

Comment: sorry my EDIT portion somehow didn't get posted, my bad. Updating it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you import `from ..models.inquiry import Inquiry` then `..` refers to

```
busgroup-backend
 src
  bus_portal_backend
   apps
```

Which does not have an `__init__.py` and thusly is not considered a package by python.